# Using Bootbox.js with Angular UI-Bootstrap

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, bootbox

I would like to use the features of [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/) with a project already using [Angular UI-Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap)
Bootbox requires JQuery as a dependency, while UI-Bootstrap removed this dependency.

Is there a simple workaround, or a project similar to Bootbox that solves this issue?

Comment: I don't know which version of Bootbox it's based on, but https://github.com/eriktufvesson/ngBootbox

Comment: According to the [bower.json](https://github.com/eriktufvesson/ngBootbox/blob/master/bower.json) file, it should be compatible with the current version of Bootbox, so I'd go with that.

Comment: @TiesonT. ngBootbox is dependent on Bootbox, which in turn is dependent on jQuery. This is what I'm trying to avoid :(

Comment: Much as I'd like you to keep using Bootbox, if the Material design works for you, they've built an equivalent at AngularJS Material: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog